# Getting error in Kibana 4 when using json input in Visualization while attempting to customize dashboard

Tags: kibana-4

I am new to the ELK stack and have it implemented with elasticsearch version 1.4.4, logstash version 1.4.2, and kibana version 4.  I am able to pull a csv file into elasticsearch using logstash and have it display in kibana.

When displaying a date from the file, the values within the date are separated out as if the dash contained within is a separator (ex. value in field is 01-01-2015, when this is displayed in kibana (regardless of display type) there will be three field entries, 01, 01, and 2015).  Kibana gives a message that this is due to it being an analyzed field.

Kibana 4 has a feature to use json directly from the dashboard builder, Visualization, to change this to a non-analyzed field so that the entire string will be used, rather than separating it.

I have tried multiple formats, but this is the one that seems it should work as kibana recognizes it as valid syntax:

```
{ "index" : "not_analyzed" }
```

but when attempting to apply the change, the dashboard does not change its structure and kibana generates the following exception:

`Visualize: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[ftpEMbcOTxu0Tdf0e8i-Ig][csvtest][0]: SearchParseException[[csvtest][0]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420092000000,\"lte\":1451627999999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"Conn Dt\",\"size\":100,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"},\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"Area Cd\"}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[csvtest][0]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [2]: [index].]]; }{[ftpEMbcOTxu0Tdf0e8i-Ig][csvtest][1]: SearchParseException[[csvtest][1]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420092000000,\"lte\":1451627999999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"Conn Dt\",\"size\":100,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"},\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"Area Cd\"}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[csvtest][1]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [2]: [index].]]; }{[ftpEMbcOTxu0Tdf0e8i-Ig][csvtest][2]: SearchParseException[[csvtest][2]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420092000000,\"lte\":1451627999999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"Conn Dt\",\"size\":100,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"},\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"Area Cd\"}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[csvtest][2]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [2]: [index].]]; }{[ftpEMbcOTxu0Tdf0e8i-Ig][csvtest][3]: SearchParseException[[csvtest][3]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420092000000,\"lte\":1451627999999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"Conn Dt\",\"size\":100,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"},\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"Area Cd\"}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[csvtest][3]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [2]: [index].]]; }{[ftpEMbcOTxu0Tdf0e8i-Ig][csvtest][4]: SearchParseException[[csvtest][4]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"@timestamp\":{\"gte\":1420092000000,\"lte\":1451627999999}}}],\"must_not\":[]}}}},\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"Conn Dt\",\"size\":100,\"order\":{\"1\":\"desc\"},\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"aggs\":{\"1\":{\"cardinality\":{\"field\":\"Area Cd\"}}}}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[csvtest][4]: query[ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(@timestamp:[1420092000000 TO 1451627999999])))],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [2]: [index].]]; }]"} less`

It can be seen within where the index: was changed to not_analyzed from analyzed; also the setting that has wildcard analyzed: true was also changed to false withing the advanced object configuration with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try index Mapping and put the date field as non-analyzed.

For Example:

```
"<index name>": {
      "mappings": {
         "<Mapping type>": {
            "properties": {
               "City": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "Date": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today with the following message:

```
Parse Failure [Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [logTime]: [offset].]]; }]
```

I was sending a date histogram aggregation request against Elasticsearch 1.4.5 with the following payload:

```
['logTime'].forEach(function (field) {
    body.aggregations[field] = {
        date_histogram: {
            field: field,
            interval: 'week',
            time_zone: '+00:00',
            offset: '15h',
            min_doc_count: 0,
            extended_bounds: {
                min: 1440946800000,
                max: 1441551599999
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**Note** the use of `offset` parameter for the `date_histogram`. This parameter is introduced in Elasticsearch version 1.5.0 only. So, my 1.4.5 ES was complaining that this `offset` key was `Unknown`.

Replacing with `post_offset` as follows solved the problem though I had to adjust the value of the `time_zone` parameter as well. As a side note, `post_offset` is deprecated and replaced with `offset` since v1.5.

```
['logTime'].forEach(function (field) {
    body.aggregations[field] = {
        date_histogram: {
            field: field,
            interval: 'week',
            time_zone: '+09:00',
            post_offset: '-9h',
            min_doc_count: 0,
            extended_bounds: {
                min: 1440946800000,
                max: 1441551599999
            }
        }
    };
});
```